# mongodb y nodejs

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Amigos, estoy haciendo un proyecto, tengo mi script de la creacion de una base de datos con mongodb, la quiero ejecutar con ayuda de nodejs, pero al momento de ejecutarlo me da un error que persiste aunque ya intente de todo.
aqui esta mi script:

```
 const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'; 

async function main() {
  const client = new MongoClient(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true });

  try {
    // Conexión al servidor de MongoDB
    await client.connect();

    // Creación de una base de datos llamada mongo_exercise
    const db = client.db('mongo_exercise');

    // Obtener la colección 'movies'
    const moviesCollection = db.collection('movies');

    // Insertar documentos en la colección 'movies'
    const movies = [
      {
        title: 'Fight Club',
        writer: 'Chuck Palahniuk',
        year: 1999,
        actors: ['Brad Pitt', 'Edward Norton'],
      },
      {
        title: 'Pulp Fiction',
        writer: 'Quentin Tarantino',
        year: 1994,
        actors: ['John Travolta', 'Uma Thurman'],
      },
      {
        title: 'Inglorious Basterds',
        writer: 'Quentin Tarantino',
        year: 2009,
        actors: ['Brad Pitt', 'Diane Kruger', 'Eli Roth'],
      },
      {
        title: 'The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey',
        writer: 'J.R.R. Tolkein',
        year: 2012,
        franchise: 'The Hobbit',
      },
      {
        title: 'The Hobbit: The Desolation of Smaug',
        writer: 'J.R.R. Tolkein',
        year: 2013,
        franchise: 'The Hobbit',
      },
      {
        title: 'The Hobbit: The Battle of the Five Armies',
        writer: 'J.R.R. Tolkein',
        year: 2012,
        franchise: 'The Hobbit',
        synopsis:
          'Bilbo and Company are forced to engage in a war against an array of combatants and keep the Lonely Mountain from falling into the hands of a rising darkness.',
      },
      {
        title: "Pee Wee Herman's Big Adventure",
      },
      {
        title: 'Avatar',
      },
    ];

    const result = await moviesCollection.insertMany(movies);
    console.log(`${result.insertedCount} documentos insertados.`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error:', err);
  } finally {
    // Cerrar la conexión
    client.close();
  }
}

main();
```

y este es el error que me regresa cuando intento ejecutarlo desde la consola de vscode mediante el comando node index.js:

```
Error: MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\E2\Desktop\ApliWeb\lab05\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:278:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

me seria de mucha ayuda si alguien podría darme un consejo de que estoy haciendo mal. El momento de ejecutar el script mi servidor de mongodb si esta en ejecución y en el puerto especificado en mi script, pero nose que pueda estar fallando.

Comment: Cambia `localhost` por `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Gracias Rene, aunque ya lo había intentado antes, ahora si funciono.

Answer (score 0):

Solución:

Reemplazar `localhost` por `127.0.0.1`.

Aveces MongoClient no detecta el localhost y hay que hacer referencia usando la IP, otras veces puede ser que existan problemas con la cache de Chrome, e igual puede ser alguna situación con las direcciones IPv6 como dicen en esta otra pregunta [Why can I connect to Mongo in node using 127.0.0.1, but not localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73133094/why-can-i-connect-to-mongo-in-node-using-127-0-0-1-but-not-localhost)

Answer (score 0):

Pueden ser varios errores:

1. Revisa si está corriendo la base de datos `systemctl status mongod.service`
2. Revisa si el puerto en el que se ejecutó es el 27017
3. cambia `localhost` por `127.0.0.1`.

Otra alternativa:
crear una cuenta en el https://cloud.mongodb.com/ generar una BD y conectarte a ella.

Esto último lo recomiendo.